# Force Titanium (iPhone) navigation group window to refresh

Tags: iphone, refresh, titanium

I am developing a data-driven application for iPhone using Appceleartor Titanium engine.

To cut it short, I have one window with first_name variable (label) on it and a button.
You click on the button, it bring you to the second window (through navigation group). ANd in this second window you can change the first_name variable.

So the question is, as the user click "Back" Button to go back to the first window in the navigation group, how do I reflect the first_name variable change?

(The first_name variable is just an abstract, the actual data change is actually  a lot bigger, and it usually is not one window after another but could drill down to 4, 5 different windows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

eventListener. add in the first window something like

```
window0.addEventListener('refreshLabel',function(e){
  label.text = e.value;
});
```

and in the second window fire the event

```
button.addEventListener('click',function(e){
  window0.fireEvent('refreshLabel',{value:"myNewContent"});
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put an event listener on the label and fire an update when the contents should he changed.

You can create an update method for the label and place it in the gloval namespace making it available to he called from the othe window.